# Custom Report XML request returns empty envelope

Tags: xml, tally

This XML request

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
        <ID>CustomersInfo</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT NAME="CustomersInfo">
                        <FORMS>CustomerForm</FORMS>
                        <TITLE>"Title"</TITLE>
                        <OBJECT> Ledger </OBJECT>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM NAME="CustomerForm">
                        <TOPPARTS>CustomerPart</TOPPARTS>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART NAME="CustomerPart">
                        <TOPLINES>TitleLine, CustomerLine</TOPLINES>
                        <REPEAT>CustomerLine: SundryDebtorLedgers</REPEAT>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE NAME="TitleLine">
                        <USE>CustomerLine</USE>
                        <LOCAL>Field: NField: Set as: "Name"</LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field: PhoneField:Set as: "Phone"</LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field: GSTField: Set as: "GST1"</LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field: StateField: Set as: "State"</LOCAL>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="CustomerLine">
                        <LEFTFIELDS>NField, PhoneField, GSTField, StateField</LEFTFIELDS>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD NAME="NField">
                        <SET>$Name</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="PhoneField">
                        <SET>$Ledgermobile</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="GSTField">
                        <SET>$Partygstin</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="StateField">
                        <SET>$StateName</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <COLLECTION NAME="SundryDebtorLedgers">
                        <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>
                        <CHILDOF>$$GroupSundryDebtors</CHILDOF>
                        <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                        <FETCH>Name, STPartyFullAdd, StateName, Pincode, LedgerContact, Ledgermobile, Email, ClosingBalance, Partygstin</FETCH>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

returns this empty response

```
<ENVELOPE></ENVELOPE>
```

But when I use this same TDL in Tally User TDLs, I see all the data. I expect the same data to be received as a response of this request. Is there something wrong with my request?

I have tried interchanging the following tags.

```
<FORM> <FORMS>
<PART> <TOPPARTS>
<LINE> <TOPLINES>
<FIELD> <LEFTFIELDS>
```

From reading the tally developer documentation, I understanding that TDL definitions and attributes can be written as XML tags. Is this correct? Is there a place to find an exhaustive list of allowed XML tags?

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Xml to get what you want

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
    <ID>CustomersInfo</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <REPORT NAME="CustomersInfo" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <FORMS>CustomersInfo</FORMS>
                </REPORT>
                <FORM NAME="CustomersInfo" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <TOPPARTS>CustomersInfo</TOPPARTS>
                    <XMLTAG>"CustomersInfo"</XMLTAG>
                </FORM>
                <PART NAME="CustomersInfo" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <TOPLINES>CustomersInfo</TOPLINES>
                    <REPEAT>CustomersInfo : Collection of Ledgers</REPEAT>
                    <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                </PART>
                <LINE NAME="CustomersInfo" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <LEFTFIELDS>Name</LEFTFIELDS>
                    <LEFTFIELDS>Ledgermobile</LEFTFIELDS>
                    <LEFTFIELDS>Partygstin</LEFTFIELDS>
                    <LEFTFIELDS>State</LEFTFIELDS>
                </LINE>
                <FIELD NAME="Name" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <SET>$Name</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>"NAME"</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD NAME="LedgerMobile" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <SET>$Ledgermobile</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>"Ledgermobile"</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD NAME="Partygstin" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <SET>$Partygstin</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>"Partygstin"</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD NAME="State" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <SET>$State</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>"State"</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                
                <COLLECTION NAME="Collection of Ledgers" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                    <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>
                    <CHILDOF>$$GroupSundryDebtors</CHILDOF>
                    <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                </COLLECTION>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
```

You can find error by yourself by using above as base xml

Tally developer documentation is not clear in every aspect and we need to refer TDL code in Tally developer application and [case studies in website](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/integration-capabilities/case_study_1.htm)

There is no exhaustive list of allowed xml tags but you can refer Tally developer application schema tab
[image]